# Comando javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou com uma dúvida, preciso criar uma função que receba um `Array` de objetos pessoas, que retorne um novo array somente com objetos pessoa que possuem idade entre 20 e 30 anos.

Alguém pode me ajudar se possível?

---

```
function pessoa(objec) {
    var olders = objec.filter(function(person){
        return person.age >= 20 && <= 30;
    });
    return olders;
}
```

Está correto dessa maneira?

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Uma boa prática para iniciarmos uma discussão saudável é ler o [Guia de Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Comece seguindo estas recomendações, principalmente sabendo quais os tipos de perguntas deve fazer, como criar um exemplo mínimo que seja completo e verificável e até mesmo o que fazer quando alguém te responder.

Comment: A própria linguagem já tem função pra isso: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: O que vc já fez em relação a isso? Edite sua pergunta e coloque o código do que fez para receber melhor ajuda

Comment: function pessoa(objec) {
    var olders = objec.filter(function(person){
        return person.age >= 20 && <= 30;
    });
    return olders;
}

Answer (score 1):

Usando o método [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)

```js
var pessoas = [{nome: 'Sérgio', idade: 35},
               {nome: 'Jéferson', idade: 25},
               {nome: 'Joaquim', idade: 19}];

var adultos = filtrarPessoas(pessoas);
console.log(adultos);

function filtrarPessoas(pessoas){
  var filtrados = pessoas.filter(function (item) {
    return item.idade >= 20 && item.idade <= 30;
  });
  
  return filtrados;
}
```

Comment: function pessoa(objec) {
    var olders = objec.filter(function(person){
        return person.age >= 20 && <= 30;
    });
    return olders;
}
 essa mandeira esta errada ?

Comment: Não. Tá certa, por que?

Comment: essa é minha duvida se esta certa. estou executando porem ainda fico na duvida no retorno.